# Cyclic subgroups and generator 1

Tags: abstract-algebra

> List all cyclic subgroups of $U_{15}$(multiplicative group of units mod $15$).

I understand what the cyclic subgroups are for all the elements except for $1$. Since this is a multiplicative group, how do the powers of $1$ generate each of these units...? Hungerford says that the cyclic group of $1$ is $U_{15}$.

Comment: The powers of $1$ are all $1$.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand the definition then (ofc I know that)... I understand why the cyclic subgroups for the other units are what they are..

Comment: If the powers of $1$ are all $1$ how does $1$ generate $U_{15}$?

Comment: As Lord Shark the Unknown mentioned, $1$ generates the trivial group, so you are right that it does not generate $U_{15}$. Either there is a typo, or you have misinterpreted what was written.

Comment: Yeah the back of the book says $\langle 1 \rangle = U_{15}$. Which the book states that this means $U_{15}$ is the cyclic subgroup generated by $1$. So then this must be a typo.